# Flutter GoogleMaps - dynamic colouring of Custom Markers

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, google-maps-markers

Flutter Google Maps allows the use of the standard/default Marker to be used on the map. You can also apply a colour to this marker programatically to add a variety of colours to your app.

However, what I can't seem to do is use this same technique to dynamically apply a colour to a custom (white) marker. Rather than make 10 custom markers with different colours I would prefer to have a plain white one, and dynamically colour it with a `Hue` or colour blend.

**Default Marker**

```
    bool bToggle = true; 

    _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(markerid),
        position: newPos,
        onTap: () {
          ...
        },
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          ...
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
           (bToggle) ? BitmapDescriptor.hueYellow : BitmapDescriptor.hueRed
        ),        
      ));
```

**Custom Marker**

```
    _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(markerid),
        position: newPos,
        onTap: () {
          ...
        },
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          ...
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5), 'assets/markers/pin-blue.png')
        ),        
      ));
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the marker doesn't change its color to either BitmapDescriptor hues is because the screen needs to be rebuilt to detect the value change on `bToggle`. What you can do here is call `setState()` on value change.